# Error for start script when trying to deploy Django-React with Heroku

Tags: reactjs, django, heroku

I am trying to deploy my first ever application, which has django for the backend and react for the frontend (with create-react-app). I followed the steps in some tutorials and managed to get my deploy build running but I am getting an error for npm start. I can't seem to find any solution, any help will be more than welcomed.

```
2021-06-11T21:48:08.784605+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-06-11T21:48:22.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-06-11T21:48:25.830113+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-06-11T21:48:28.292792+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-06-11T21:48:28.292815+00:00 app[web.1]: > ui@0.1.0 start /app
2021-06-11T21:48:28.292815+00:00 app[web.1]: > serve -s build
2021-06-11T21:48:28.292815+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-06-11T21:48:28.297425+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: serve: not found
2021-06-11T21:48:28.304774+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-06-11T21:48:28.305084+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2021-06-11T21:48:28.305267+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2021-06-11T21:48:28.305429+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2021-06-11T21:48:28.309100+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! ui@0.1.0 start: `serve -s build`
2021-06-11T21:48:28.309179+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2021-06-11T21:48:28.309293+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-06-11T21:48:28.309384+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the ui@0.1.0 start script.
2021-06-11T21:48:28.309470+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-06-11T21:48:28.315822+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-06-11T21:48:28.316160+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-06-11T21:48:28.316161+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-06-11T21_48_28_310Z-debug.log
2021-06-11T21:48:28.376386+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-06-11T21:48:28.543859+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-06-11T21:50:15.500360+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=taby-bt.herokuapp.com request_id=3c84bb9a-a59b-489c-9d9d-19c886d42c72 fwd="5.15.164.88" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2021-06-11T21:50:16.200509+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=taby-bt.herokuapp.com request_id=1d44fdaf-4dcd-4f91-a28f-93e19c3fd9ca fwd="5.15.164.88" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2021-06-11T21:51:16.423492+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=taby-bt.herokuapp.com request_id=5d78951d-6a1f-45cd-8835-6b52b770e878 fwd="5.15.164.88" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2021-06-11T21:51:17.062971+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=taby-bt.herokuapp.com request_id=d79908e7-f51b-4e69-8563-17aa1aff8792 fwd="5.15.164.88" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

In my settings.py I have this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS =[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"build/static")
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_STORAGE =  'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

in package.json I have these:

```
 "engines": {
    "node": "15.5.1",
    "npm": "6.14.11"
  }

 "scripts": {
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "serve -s build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "postinstall": "npm run build"
  },
```

And my Procfile looks like this

```
release:python manage.py migrate
web:gunicorn chatbot.wsgi --log-file -
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to be more specific about what you are having trouble with or what you are expecting. It's important to add code showing what have you done so far or what errors did you found during the process.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to be vague. I edited the post with some info. I have never worked with Heroku before so I don't really know if I included the right info. Thank you for understanding that I am new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error indicates heroku cannot start the server.

I think you did not install gunicorn package.

- pip install gunicorn

and in settings.py

```
 ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["127.0.0.1","localhost","YOUR_APP.herokuapp.com"]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it was not a problem with my gunicorn, but rather with whitenoise. After updating it to `5.2.0` it works.